# Error when overwriting conflicting files to link node.js

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am trying to reinstall node.js via homebrew and it is installed but not linked. When I try to overwrite conflicting files with **brew link --overwrite node**, I get the error below. Is there a way to fix this? (I'm really new to this)

bubblenote$ **brew update && brew install node**

```
Already up-to-date.
Warning: node 10.5.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
```

bubblenote$ **brew link node**

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
Target /usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit
already exists.
```

You may want to remove it:

```
rm '/usr/local/share/doc/node/gdbinit'
```

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
 brew link --overwrite node
```

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

bubblenote$ **brew link --overwrite node**

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit /usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.
```

This seems to indicate you do not have write access to the file or that the file is read-only.

Try removing the file manually,if you can't then indeed you do not have write permissions. If that is the case try running the command with `sudo` and see if that works.

**EDIT:**
Try the following to make the directory writable

```
chmod +w <directory>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried sudo rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'  and other files that need to be removed. I checked that they don't exist, yet I'm still getting the same error that  /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

Comment: Hmm, I did  chmod +w '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'  and it said there is no such file or directory. I tried brew link node after and it still says  /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.  Am I just typing the command wrong or does the file not actually exist?

Comment: Did you try ```+w '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/``` ? Another problem could be that brew is expecting a file that doesn't exist (yet) Manually creating an empty file could also fix your issue.